# Linux Mint installation and partitions restore

Tags: windows-7, linux, linux-mint, partition-recovery

I tried to install Linux Mint and accidentally selected to install over other OS. After that it imediatly transfered me to where I must select my time zone. I aborted install, restarted PC and looks like I now have single empty partition. Is it possible to recover my previos partitions with my windows and data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

Maybe start with `boot-repair` if unsuccessful, start with a recovery disk. Do not select the install option. Do not mount the partition.
If you can avoid to physically put that disk as 1st it's better because some distributions can try to mount the *swap* over it.

Read a lot before to act, some of those tools may be available or installable with your distribution disk or via internet.

- `boot-repair`
- `ddrescue` gddrescue package
- `testdisk`
- `smartctl` smartmontools package
- `fixparts`

Some references to start

[1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
  [2] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair ,
      http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
      **http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/**
  [3] http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html